# extract text from nested div using xpath

Tags: xpath

I would like to get the text inside the h2 tag

```
<p>Mi. 5. Dezember 2018</p>
<h2>Slam: Jägerschlacht</h2>
<p>Einlass 19:30 Uhr // Beginn 20:30 Uhr</p>
<p>Tickets: 4€</p>
```

out of [this](https://www.gruener-jaeger-stpauli.de/) page with xpath. The problem is i cant find the right xpath with all the div. All i get when i use this python code

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.gruener-jaeger-stpauli.de/")
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
text = tree.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/a[1]/h2")

print (text)
```

is [< Element h2 at 0x25ae6341a98 >]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use a handwritten XPath instead of a generated path.

Try it like this to get the first `h2`-element (selecting all text-node children using `/text()`)

```
"//a[contains(@class, 'event_box_gj')][1]/h2/text()")
```

or drop `[1]` to get all of them.